# What are the different output streams built in to visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Are there output streams besides:

```
    Console.WriteLine(data)
    Trace.WriteLine(data)
    Debug.WriteLine(data)
```

Any notable nuances or uses of each(for example: which by default go to command,output,immediate?)
Also which if any are available to show as output from the external tools window when the target is a windows application (Use Output window is grayed out)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are. For example when you install TFS all TFS source control messages are displayed in the "Team Foundation Server" window. However I have no idea on how you'd create your own window or how to send WriteLine to it.